# Unity - How to make the accelerometer of object move more smoothly?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, accelerometer

I want to make my character to move smoothly when I tilt my phone. How I can make it to move smoothly and the velocity and the speed increases as the slope of the phone?

```
void AccelerometerMove()
{

    float x = Input.acceleration.x;
    Debug.Log("X = " + x);

    if (x < -0.1f)
    {
        MoveLeft();
    }
    else if (x > 0.1f)
    {
        MoveRight();
    }
    else
    {
        SetVelocityZero();
    }
}

public void SetVelocityZero()
{
    rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
}

public void MoveLeft()
{
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(-speed, 0);
    //transform.Translate(Vector2.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    transform.eulerAngles = new Vector2(0, 180);
}

public void MoveRight()
{
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(speed, 0);
    //transform.Translate(Vector2.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    transform.eulerAngles = new Vector2(0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer about using a moving average/low-pass filter [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21631888/unity3d-accelerometer-sensitivity)

You could achieve a similar effect by using the Vector3.Lerp function.